# Proper way to delete an Autodesk Forge Bucket using a Python Script

Tags: python, autodesk-forge

I am working on a project to convert various file types to .stl format using Autodesk Forge and [this](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/translate-zip-source-file-to-stl/) tutorial. As mentioned in the tutorial, the process is to make a bucket, upload an object, convert it, and finally download it. After conversion, I would like to delete the bucket I created, so that my code can make a bucket with the same name again.

I am using a python script to accomplish this, and I found [this](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/3ds-max/learn-explore/caas/simplecontent/content/forge-3ds-max-delete-bucket.html) tutorial online to delete a bucket. However, trying to replicate the same process gives me error 403 (for more details on error codes, see [this](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/signedresources-:id-DELETE/) link). My code is as below

```
print "Step 8 - Deleting Bucket...",

h = {
'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + ACCESS_TOKEN, "Content-Type": "application/json", "x-ads-region":  "US"
}

r=requests.delete("https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/%s"%(BUCKET_NAME), headers=h)

if r.status_code == 200:
    print("Done!")
else:
    print("")
    print("Error Executing STEP 8 - Something went wrong, error code: " + str(r.status_code) + ", exiting")
    raise(SystemExit(6))
```

BUCKET_NAME and ACCESS_TOKEN contain name of bucket and Access tokens respectively. Can someone point out what's wrong with the code?

EDIT: I have the bucket:create bucket:read bucket:update scopes. Do I need to add another scope to make sure the bucket can be deleted?

Comment: That resource suggests that your headers should be `{"Authorization": token,"Content-Type": "application/json", "x-ads-region":  bucket_region}` where `token` is the type followed by the token itself. I'm no expert in this area, but I would think that, because you received `403 FORBIDDEN`, you should verify the Authorization key of your headers.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am sure the ACCESS_TOKEN is correct, because I am using the same token to accomplish other things successfully (like file conversion, downloading, etc.). I only get an error in bucket deletion step.

Comment: @101arrowz I think I need to change the bucket scopes to enable deletion. Let me try that. The error code says that the authorization was successful but permission denies, which makes me think it has to do something with the bucket scope.

Comment: Yup, that solved it. I needed to have a bucket:delete scope!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add a bucket:delete scope to enable deletion. I only had bucket:read, bucket:create and bucket:update scopes.